# Increase the size of col-lg-*

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I wonder if it is possible to somehow increase the size of the col-md-* classes if the screen size is for example bigger then 1600px. Then 95px per col are to small for me. With media queries I didn't found a possibility to change the size of the single col so maybe you have a hint.

Regards

Comment: You can edit the bootstrap css file and modify the value at hand ? for the @media of 1600px.

Comment: Sorry, I had such a brainlaag. Ur totally right. If you want to answer it, go on :)

Comment: You can customize bootstrap - http://getbootstrap.com/customize/. It has a Media queries breakpoints section which defines the screen sizes.

Comment: A question: When I set `@container-lg (@container-large-desktop + 200)` in the customize the result is as I wanted but it doesn't scale correctly when i resize the window. Any clue why?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the bootstrap css file and modify the value at hand for the @media of 1600px.